# Check if key exists else

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Dictionary with userimages. For each game I run an method in which I add the opponents image, but since I am able to play against the same opponent multiple times I store the images in a dictionary list with the opponents ID as key. My idea was to check if the opponents image already was in the dictionary and get it from there instead of loading it again. I am trying to do so like this:

```
IEnumerator getOppImages(int gobject, string imageurl, string oppID){

    if(oppimages.ContainsKey(oppID)){

        UITexture picture = GameObject.Find("Game"+gobject+"/Background/ProfileImg").GetComponent<UITexture>();
        picture.mainTexture = oppimages[oppID];

    } else {

        var oppImageRequest = new WWW(imageurl);
        yield return oppImageRequest;
        oppimages.Add(oppID,oppImageRequest.texture);

        UITexture picture = GameObject.Find("Game"+gobject+"/Background/ProfileImg").GetComponent<UITexture>();
        picture.mainTexture = oppImageRequest.texture;

    }

}
```

The issue here is that it doesn't seem to react on the "if(oppimages.ContainsKey(oppID)){". Am I doing this all wrong or am I missing something?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

-------------------- EDIT ------------------

Here is how I create the Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, Texture2D> oppimages = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();
```

An oppID could look like this: QonTtQV9Px

Comment: put  a break point on the needed line to see if the check  was done or not

Comment: Your implementation seems correct as far as I can tell. Are you sure each opponent always has the same oppID?

Comment: try contains , I have a sneaking suspicion you aren't using IDictionary

Comment: I have added some code to the original message showing how my Dictionary is set up. I still haven't found the solution :-/

Comment: Since your dictionary isn't static, are you sure the dictionary used against the opponent the first time, is the same instance as the one you're using the second time? If the object this script is in was destroyed, then you'd lose the list of opponents and their images.

Comment: Well, when going through the method and I come across an object which already has been loaded it doesn't get the "if" but goes to "else" and throws this error: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.

Comment: Might be getting closer... It seems like when I ask for the if(){... it haven't updated the dictionary. How can I update/refresh the dictionary before I check?